# Dell Inspiron 580 not installing ATI radeon HD 5570 graphics card

Tags: windows-7

I just bought a Dell Inspiron 580 and an ATI Radeon HD 5570 PCI. I installed the card on the motherboard and inserted the dvd that came with. I got a screen that said Setup Application has stopped working. I'm getting really frustrated here! I've tried looking online for troubleshooting help... Nada. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is there anything else in the error message or in Event Viewer? Also, try downloading the drivers from the ATI site, the drivers that come on the disk are usually outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone to the card manufacturers website to download the latest driver? Be sure to pick the correct model card, and OS 32 or 64bit. You can find more details on the [AMD Support Search](http://support.amd.com/us/psearch/Pages/psearch.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.36.3.4&contentType=KB+Article&ostype=&keywords=&items=20) page.